# Create runtime parameters that can be shared among other pipelines in azure-pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I wonder is it possible that to create a runtime parameters that can be shared with other pipelines in azure-pipelines?

For instance, I have the following parameters in 1 pipeline (e.g. my-app):

```
parameters:
  - name: Environment
    default: DEV
    values:
      - DEV
      - UAT
  - name: Branch
    displayName: Check Out Branch
    type: string
    default: main
```

These parameters can be shared into another pipeline (e.g. my-svc).

Will that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You could do that by having input parameters also in your second pipeline and call the second pipeline from the first pipeline using the parameters provided on your first pipeline. There is not a shared thing for parameters on multiple pipelines.

But there is a shared library between multiples pipelines using variables. You can define variables on a Library that will be used across multiples pipelines. In order to do that you should refer/call the variable group on each pipeline.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. What I try to achieve is allow each pipeline input its own value before user triggering the pipeline to run. It might be difficult to update the runtime parameter for each pipeline if each pipeline has its own runtime parameters defined in its own azure-pipelines.yml